# Document breaking page and leaving empty space

Tags: pdftex, page-breaking, classicthesis

I am using the "Classic Thesis" package to write a document. As since it's a mathematics manuscript, it consists of plenty of formulas and questions answers. But unfortunately, latex is trying to keep the whole block on the same page and is creating a lot of blank spaces.

[image: Example of wasted space.]

As you can see, latex shifted the solution to another page while half of it could easily fit on the previous page.

```
\newcommand\Problem{%
    \stepcounter{problem}%
    \noindent\textbf{\theproblem.}~%
    \setcounter{solution}{0}%
}
\newcommand{\TheSolution}[1]{%
    \begin{addmargin}[2em]{1em}\doublespacing
      \textbf{Solution:}\\{#1}\\%
    \end{addmargin}
}
\newcommand{\ASolution}[1]{%
    \begin{addmargin}[2em]{1em}\doublespacing
      \stepcounter{solution}%
      \textbf{Solution \thesolution:}\\{#1}\\%
    \end{addmargin}
}
```

The preamble cannot be added as it's a whole 2 different files, you can get the gist [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis?lang=en). What can be ammemded to force latex to break page only when the capacity is reached.

Comment: why are you not using section heading commands? `\textbf{Solution}\\ ` would allow a page break after the **Solution** "heading"

Comment: I have plenty of question answers in the document.

Comment: yes but what I mean is that you are not using any of the latex mechanisms for headings

Comment: Sometimes, I have more than one solution to a problem. In such cases, I am trying to automate the "Solution #", hence the defined macros. With that in practise, I thought about adding one for singular solutions too. Hope I was able to represent myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't include the MWE, only a general advice is possible.

Typically, formulas as on the page 34 of your example cannot be divided between pages. However `\allowdisplaybreaks` from `amsmath` package allows it.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be a plausible solution. Is there a way to declare it globally?

Comment: Nevermind, it is a global command.